# Is life possible on other celestial objects (apart from planets) even theoretically?

Tags: planet, life, astronomical-unit

For example, asteroids, comets, stars, heliosphere etc?

Comment: The heliosphere is no body or object - it's the area of influence of the Sun. So yes. *in* the heliosphere life does exist. It writes on StackExchange messages pondering where life exists.

Comment: Brown dwarfs could be the most abundant in terms of total potentially habitable volume site for Earth-like life: see [Lingam & Loeb 2019](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.11410).

Answer (score 1):

The term you should be looking for is "[**Panspermia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panspermia)".

> It is a hypothesis that life exists throughout the Universe, distributed by space dust, meteoroids, asteroids, comets, and planetoids, as well as by spacecraft carrying unintended contamination by microorganisms.

You can go through the WP article for an exhaustive discussion. I am going to highlight the points required for this question:

- In November 2019, scientists reported detecting, for the first time, sugar molecules, including ribose, in meteorites, suggesting that chemical processes on asteroids can produce some fundamentally essential bio-ingredients important to life, and supporting the notion of an RNA world prior to a DNA-based origin of life on Earth, and possibly, as well, the notion of panspermia
- In 2020, [Hayabusa2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayabusa2) brought back a capsule containing a sample of carbon-rich asteroid dust from the asteroid 162173 Ryugu. Scientists believe this could provide clues about the ancient delivery of water and organic molecules to Earth.
- In May 2016, the Rosetta Mission team reported the presence of glycine, methylamine and ethylamine in the coma of [67P/Churyumov-Gerasimenko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/67P/Churyumov%E2%80%93Gerasimenko). This, plus the detection of phosphorus, is consistent with the hypothesis that comets played a crucial role in the emergence of life on Earth.
- In 2013, Dale Warren Griffin, a microbiologist working at the United States Geological Survey proposed that viruses in comets that may be pathogenic to humans
- It is also hypothesized that comets can harbor life for interstellar travel. For e.g. results from *SEEDS* and *LiFE* conculded that after an 18-month exposure, some seeds and lichens (*Stichococcus* sp. and *Acarospora* sp., a lichenized fungal genus) may be capable to survive interplanetary travel.

If you are looking for colonization, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colonization_of_the_asteroids

Regarding stars, there shouldn't be any life because they are extremely hot and have harsh conditions.

You can read this article for more information: https://www.seti.org/comets-and-asteroids-may-be-spreading-life-across-galaxy